# Change pages margins (right & left)

Tags: margins

I have a problem with the margins that don't seem appropriate ... and i want to change these margins to make it equal on the left and the right, this is a sample of my code :

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, 12pt, blue, rgb,]{tubsbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}
\usepackage[activate]{pdfcprot}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\title{MULTI-CORE SYSTEM}
\logo{\includegraphics{images/c3e_logo.pdf}}
\titleabstract{\lipsum[2]}
\titlepicture{images/infozentrum.jpg}

\begin{document}
....
....
\end{document}
```

and this is how the margins in the pages look like :
[image: pages margins]
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You say that "i want to change it". What do you want to change it to? Please advise.

Comment: i edited my question please have a look again

Comment: Not having access to the `tubsbook` document class, the following recommendation is untested: Add the option `oneside` to the list of options included in the `\documentclass` instruction.

Comment: solved thank you Mico  .... Now all the pages have the same marins